# Issue with buy one, discount another product in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

So I have almost achieved my goal - to create a new discounted price on a specific product, should another specific product be in the customer's cart.

I am using ACF to select the core product and the discounted one, which is all being pulled fine. The issue lies in the order in which the products are added to the cart.

If I add the discounted product BEFORE the core product, the discounted product correctly adjusts to $9.99 (the ACF determined new price). However, if I add the core product first, and THEN add the product that should be discounted, the price remains the same - with no discount applied.

I used this code for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500323/16291715

My code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'boga_discount', 20, 1 );
function boga_discount( $cart ) {

if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
    return;

if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
    return;

// First loop to check if CORE product is in cart
foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $is_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'] == 1249 ? true : false;
}

// Second loop change prices
foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object (or the variation product object)
    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    // Here we target DISCOUNT ID 17
    if( $product->get_id() == 1361 ) {

        // GET THE NEW PRICE
        $new_price = 9.99; // <== Add your code HERE

        // When product CORE product is in cart
        if( $is_in_cart ){
            $product->set_price( $new_price );
        }
    }
}
}
```

I can't understand why this would happen for the life of me, but I am sure there is some minor detail I am missing.

Comment: This looks like a scope issue. Try defining your variable `$is_in_cart` outside of your for loop like this: `$is_in_cart = false;`. it should then be available when you are within your second for loop.

Comment: @wetmarble thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue either. I'm really stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop you have

```php
$is_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'] == 813 ? true : false;
```

Suppose there are 2 products in the cart 813 & 815.

While going through the cart items (first loop), suppose product 813 is first found, so `$is_in_cart` is true. Then in the same loop, however, `$cart_item['product_id']` is now equal to 815. The condition says again, it is equal to 813? this does not match, so `$is_in_cart` will be false. That's the issue

---

So you don't need to use 2 foreach loops, this should suffice:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Settings
    $core_product = 813;
    $discounted_product = 815;
    $new_price = 9.99; 
    
    // Initialize
    $flag_core_product = false;
    $flag_discounted_product = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Compare
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $core_product ) {
            $flag_core_product = true;
        } elseif ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $discounted_product ) {
            $flag_discounted_product = true;
            
            // Store data (discounted product)
            $cart_item_data = $cart_item['data'];            
        }
    }
    
    // Both are true
    if ( $flag_core_product && $flag_discounted_product ) {
        // Set new price
        $cart_item_data->set_price( $new_price );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'action_woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! If you have a moment, would you mind telling me what piece of this code made the difference? Having trouble deciphering what was stumping me.

Comment: @ChronicSmoke27 I've updated my answer, with the issue in your code.